# setBackgroudColor to NSView

Tags: cocoa, initialization, nsview, init, nscolor

What I miss? color won't change.

```
#import "controller.h"
#import "backgroundView.h"
@implementation controller
-(void)awakeFromNib {
    backgroundView *background = [[backgroundView alloc] init];
    [background setBackgroudColor:[NSColor whiteColor]];
    //also didn't work 
    //[background setBackgroudColor:[[NSColor whiteColor] retain]];
}
@end

//backgroundView.h
#import <Cocoa/Cocoa.h>

@interface backgroundView : NSView{
    NSColor *color;
}
-(void)setBackgroudColor:(NSColor*)newColor;
@end
#import "backgroundView.h"
@implementation backgroundView
-(void)dealloc{
    [super dealloc];
}
-(void)setBackgroudColor:(NSColor*)newColor{
    color = newColor;
    [self setNeedsDisplay:YES];
}
-(void)drawRect:(NSRect)rect{
    [color setFill];
    NSRectFill(rect);
}
@end
```

Answer (score 2):

1. You should retain `newColor` in `setBackgroundColor:` method.
2. Release `color` ivar in `dealloc`
3. In awakeFromNib method you initialize your view with `init`, but designated initializer is `initWithFrame:`
4. There's no code where you add newly created view to superview.
5. You can also try to use `set` instead of `setFill` for `NSColor`

Comment: can you give me a sample how should I use initWithFrame?

Comment: @user840250: You use it the same way as `init`, but you pass it the rectangle you want the view to have as its frame. For more information, see the View Programming Guide: http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CocoaViewsGuide/Introduction/Introduction.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40002978 and the NSView class reference: http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ApplicationKit/Classes/NSView_Class/Reference/NSView.html#//apple_ref/occ/cl/NSView

Answer (score 0):

You are creating a view in `awakeFromNib` which is attached to nowhere. Instead you should change the custom class of your view in Interface Builder, setup an outlet on this view and call `setBackgroudColor:` on it.

Also, classes should start with a capital letter so `backgroundView` should be `BackgroundView`. As Andriy said, make sure to fix the memory management of your `color` ivar.